# Four NTFS partition + a ex4 on a MBR partition scheme

Tags: linux, partitioning, disk-management

I'm about to install Linux OS in my computer. Using Windows' Disk Management, I shrunk a partition for Linux. After pressing OK on making a simple volume, Windows request to make the disk to dynamic, I declined. It's still unallocated. There are already 4 partition in my hard drive(System reserve,C,Recovery and E) which is the max for MBR partition scheme. If I install a certain Linux distro on that unallocated space, will it be ok?

Comment: You won't be able to because you already have 4 partition but you knew that, so its not clear, what your question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just installed Linux,alongside with windows 8 
works fine and this is my scheme:

[image: scheme]

I had windows in 1 ntfs and win boot in another ntfs.
You can have maximum 4 primary partitions. So your allocated place should be extended partition, that's why windows asks you make it as dynamic. Just use scheme:

```
-Primary
--Extended (in unallocated)
---Ext4(root)
---Swap
```

You can add more Ext4 partitions if you like /home /usr. This is basic scheme then you pick install linux alongside with windows, got all you need and works fine with GRUB dualboot. Everything you need gonna be installed in unallocated and Grub gonna change your windows Bootloader.

Comment: Note that Windows "dynamic disks" aren't the same as MBR extended partitions. Dynamic disks (aka Logical Disk Manager) are more like Linux LVM.